# How to get the direction of a point in the map in iOS?

Tags: ios, maps, compass-geolocation

I need to mark a point in the map and get the direction of that point (like in a compass) related to the angle that the phone is currently being held in. Any tips would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2571801/1038204. Should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector for the angle of the phone will be: `av = (cos(phone_angle), sin(phone_angle))`

Your vector for the angle from the phone to the destination will be `dv = (x_phone_location - x_dest, y_phone_location - y_dest)`

Find the magnitude (length) of each of the two above vectors. Call these magnitudes `mag_dv` and `mag_av`

You can then do the dot product of the destination vector and the phone angle vector.

`angle = arccos( ((dv_x * av_x)+(dv_y * av_y)) / (mag_av * mag_dv) )`